# How to download Magento Orders for WSI Compliance mode with Complex Filter?

Tags: php, magento

I am very new to magento. I want to download orderlist from Magento for WSI Compliance Mode where I can pass start and end date to Complex Filters.
For Ex :

```html
$filters = array(
  'complex_filter' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'created_at',
      'value' => array('key' => 'from', 'value' => "2015-01-05 00:00:00")
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'created_at',
      'value' => array('key' => 'to', 'value' => "2016-02-05 23:59:59")
    )
)
);
```

But when I debugged it in Magento file : app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php , it receives following filter:

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [complex_filter] => Array
        (
            [created_at] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [key] => to
                    [value] => 2016-02-05 23:59:599
                )
        )
)
```

In it from date is not getting appear on magento end

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on following link of stackoverflow:

[Combined complex filter for ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579639/combined-complex-filter-for-ranges)

I used following code:

```html
$complex_filter' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'CREATED_AT',
    'value' => array('key' => 'from', 'value' => "2016-02-01 00:00:00")
  ),
  array(
    'key' => 'created_at',
    'value' => array('key' => 'to', 'value' => "2016-02-05 23:59:59")
  )
);
```