# Combined complex filter for ranges in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, soap, magento-1.9

On Magento 1.8 SOAP APIv2, i'm looking for a way to get a date range to retrieve information from the SOAP API. I have consulted a query from stackoverflow itself i.e [Combined complex filter for ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579639/combined-complex-filter-for-ranges). Need to apply same type of complex filters in my node project.
Curently using magento node wrapper i.e https://github.com/MadisonReed/magentoapi

```
exports.find = function (req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function (done) {
      magento.login(function(err, sessId) {
        if (err) {
          // deal with error
          console.log('login error:' + err);
          return;
        }
        done(err, done);
        // http://localhost/api/rest/customers
      });
    },

    function (filteredCustomer, done) {
      var attributes = [];
      var filteredCustomer = [];
      magento.customer.list({filters: [  ]},function(err, customerCollection) {
        _.forEach(customerCollection, function(customer, key) {
          var attributes = _.pick(customer, [
            'customer_id',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'gender',
            'credit_value',
            'customer_referral_code',
          ]);
          var customerDocument = {
            'email': customer.email,
            'number': customer.contact_no,
            'created_at': Date.now(),
            'initialSource': 'magento',
            'attributes': attributes
          };
          filteredCustomer.push(customerDocument);
        });
        done(filteredCustomer);
      });
    },
    function (filteredCustomer, done) {
      console.log(filteredCustomer);
      if(!err){
        done(filteredCustomer);
      }
    }
  ],
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

output:

```
[ 
 { 
    email: 'rht.rai2@gmail.com',
    number: '1313543132',
    created_at: 1478785224233,
    initialSource: 'magento',
    attributes: 
     { customer_id: '1',
       created_at: '2016-03-10 04:39:16',
       updated_at: '2016-10-03 10:09:21',
       firstname: 'rohit',
       lastname: 'Rai',
       gender: '1',
       credit_value: '0.0000',
       customer_referral_code: 'dS518' 
     } 
 },   
 {
    email: 'rajveer@gmailj.com',
    number: '9088694978',
    created_at: 1478785224233,
    initialSource: 'magento',
    attributes: 
     { 
       customer_id: '2',
       created_at: '2016-04-10 23:52:05',
       updated_at: '2016-11-04 05:22:09',
       firstname: 'rajveer',
       gender: '1',
       credit_value: '0.0000',
       customer_referral_code: 'Cw624' 
     } 
 },
 { 
    email: 'rohit@happilyunmarried.com',
    number: '1321321231',
    created_at: 1478785224233,
    initialSource: 'magento',
    attributes: 
     { 
       customer_id: '3',
       created_at: '2016-07-11 05:00:55',
       updated_at: '2016-11-07 10:03:54',
       firstname: 'rohit',
       gender: '1',
       credit_value: '0.0000',
       customer_referral_code: 'aj318' 
     } 
 } 
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the way to send data in magento  and get the required result in Node. Its working smooth. Hope it helps.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var path = require('path'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller')),
  _ = require('lodash'),
  Customers = mongoose.model('Customers'),
    async = require('async'),
      moment = require('moment');

var MagentoAPI = require('magento');

var magento = new MagentoAPI({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 80,
  path: '/happilyustraa/api/xmlrpc/',
  login: 'rhtrai',
  pass: 'rohitisla'
});





exports.find = function (req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function (done) {
      magento.login(function(err, sessId) {
        if (err) {
          // deal with error
          console.log('login error:' + err);
          return;
        }
        done(err, done);
        // http://localhost/api/rest/customers
      });
    },

    function (filteredCustomer, done) {
      var attributes = [];
      var filteredCustomer = [];
      magento.customer.list({filters: {"CREATED_AT": {'from': "2016-03-10 04:39:16"}, "created_at":{ 'to': "2016-04-10 23:52:05"}   } },function(err, customerCollection) {
        _.forEach(customerCollection, function(customer, key) {
          // var attributes = _.pick(customer, [
          //   'customer_id',
          //   'created_at',
          //   'updated_at',
          //   'firstname',
          //   'lastname',
          //   'gender',
          //   'credit_value',
          //   'customer_referral_code',
          // ]);
          // var customerDocument = {
          //   'email': customer.email,
          //   'number': customer.contact_no,
          //   'created_at': Date.now(),
          //   'initialSource': 'magento',
          //   'attributes': attributes
          // };
          // filteredCustomer.push(customerDocument);
          console.log(customer);
        });
        done(filteredCustomer);
      });
    },
    function (filteredCustomer, done) {
      // console.log(filteredCustomer);
      if(!err){
        done(filteredCustomer);
      }
    }
  ],
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```